# jQuery - both if else statements executing on page load

Tags: jquery

Edit: both if else statements executing. - 
I have a table with buttons in it. On page load, if the label of the button is 'Hello', I want to change it to something else. I have if-else statement but all the time, both if else statements are being executed. I do not what is wrong here.

```
 $(document).ready( function() {

   if($('button').val() == "Hello" ) {
      alert("Hello I am in if");
      $(this).removeClass('btn-danger');
      $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
      $(this).text('ifif');
    }
    else {
     alert("Hello I am in else");
     $(this).removeClass('btn-primary');
     $('button').addClass('btn-danger');
     $('button').text('elseelse');
    }
  });
```

Everytime, the label of the button changes to elseelse even when the initial label of button is 'Hello'. First it goes inside if and changes the label to ifif and then goes inside else too.It works fine if I put it in a click event function. But on page load it does not work correctly.

Your responses will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Button", or "Button ***s***"?

Comment: Post your makrup as well.. POst the HTML

Comment: how many buttons are there in the page

Comment: There are many buttons. The last column of the table has buttons only. This is just an example. In real case scenario, I want to change the text of all the buttons which have passed written in them and also add css class to it

Comment: You might want to check the order in which your script is running, if it's at the very top of your page (somewhere in the `<head>`) then there are chances it might not work as all the `buttons` might not have loaded by then.

Comment: @badZoke I am using $(document).ready( function..
so that should not matter

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `text()` method, not the `val()` method to get the button's text. Also, please note that `$('button')` will select all the buttons in your page, wich is probably not what you want.

```
$('button').text() == "Hello"
```

Additionnaly, I noticed you are using `$(this)` in the document ready handler, wich seems wrong, because `this` won't be a reference to your button. You should do something like:

```
$(document.ready(function () {
    var $btn = $('#your_button_id');

    if ($btn.text() === 'Hello') {
        $btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
        //...
    }
});
```

> "actually I want all the buttons to be selected."

According to these different requirements, here's what you could do:

http://jsfiddle.net/WpJpV/1/

HTML

```
<button class="btn-danger">Hello</button>
<button class="btn-danger">Hello</button>
<button class="btn-danger">Hello></button>
<button class="btn-danger">Hello></button>
<button class="btn-primary">Yo</button>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    var classes = 'btn-danger btn-primary';

    $('button:not(:contains(Hello))').toggleClass(classes).text('elseelse');
    $('button:contains(Hello)').toggleClass(classes).text('ifif');

});
```

Comment: actually I want all the buttons to be selected.

Comment: @user2174925 Then you need to use a `.each()` and cycle through all of the buttons. Otherwise it will be just the first button on the page that it will do the check against.

Comment: @plalx using text() method does not help. using val() method runs fine in the click event. So I am thinking the problem is during page load

Comment: @BlakePlumb yes, that is not a worry. I can handle that once my if statement starts executing

Comment: @plalx I used the code that you gave.. It is still giving me elseelse. I don't know why it is not working. I tried with $(function() {... and also put it in $(document).ready( function () {... 
the code looks fine.. I do not know what is going on .. in my html I have ..

Comment: @plalx I think I am getting somewhere with this code. I used alert..
if(ss == '5') {
alert($('button').text())
}
The else statement is running twice after if is executed. First I see Hello in the button, then alert comes and I see ifif on the button, then another alert comes again.. and I see elseelse, after I click ok one more time, it stays elseelse but toggles the class so that is how I know else is being executed twice
(I am trying this only with one button for now). Thanks

Comment: @user2174925, Please try to setup a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem. It will help us figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('button').not(':contains(Hello)').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').text('elseelse');

    $('button:contains(Hello)').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary').text('ifif');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDXg5/3/)

Or

```
$(function(){
    $('button').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.text() == 'Hellow'){
            $this.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary').text('ifif');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').text('elseelse');
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDXg5/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is same as above. But I am not getting anywhere. please read the comments in the above answer provided by @plalx

Comment: @user2174925 please share the buttons used and the table

Comment: @user2174925 We have provided the demo's please edit the sample to recreate the problem

Comment: @user2174925 is it case sensitive

Comment: The code provided by you is good. The problem is not reproduced on fiddle. As mentioned, if I put the code in click event, it works fine. The problem is when it is happening on page load; both if and else are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.each()` function, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UCEAw/1/

```
$('button').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'hello') {
        $(this).text('Hello');
    } else {
        $(this).text('World');
    }
});
```

Comment: it gives me 'World'. I need Hello

Comment: both if and else are being executed